# Are there powerful text generators that preserve attribution?

Tags: gpt, capabilities

Traditional text generation works by playing a big game of Mad Libs. (A famous example is [the Dada Engine](https://dev.null.org/dadaengine/manual-1.0/dada_toc.html), used in [the Postmodernism Generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postmodernism_Generator).) You could, if you so chose, go in and track down the source of every single phrase the algorithm produces: you could just as easily (nay, *more easily*) have it output complete attribution information along with the words it writes.

Compared to what came before, GPT-2 is a pretty powerful model. However, it is – like [Markov chain generators](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Markov_chain_text_generator) – a [big statistical aggregation](https://xkcd.com/1838/) of the corpus used to train it. This makes it [difficult to say](https://arxiv.org/abs/2203.07618) what source data contributed to a particular output; even when a GPT model quotes [entire passages verbatim](https://nitter.net/stefankarpinski/status/1410971061181681674), one can't tell where exactly it got that from.

Are there methods that give the best of both worlds? Text generation as powerful as GPT-2, but with a clear and comprehensible chain of provenance?

Comment: This is a complete misunderstanding of how the text is generated. "Knowledge" doesn't need to be attributed, even if you use very similar words to someone else to express it. If ChatGPT says "A bed is a piece of furniture for sleeping." which dictionary does it need to attribute that tidbit to? If I ask ChatGPT to write a poem about "slithy toves", I fully expect it to repeat lines from Lewis Carroll because that is likely the only pattern it has in its model for that phrase. The best that can be done is to be transparent about the data it was trained on.

Comment: Bing seems to properly cite its sources, is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @Mast To my knowledge, Bing uses a technique similar to [the technique described in Rebecca J. Stones's answer](https://genai.stackexchange.com/a/93/10), which isn't quite what I'm looking for. That's basically just plugging a search engine into the back of the language model: it's still at risk of saying things that aren't in the sources given.

Comment: Well, congratulation for [the first HNQ](https://genai.stackexchange.com/posts/92/timeline) :)

Comment: @ColleenV It's a bit more nuanced than that. [Jonathan Bailey's article](https://www.plagiarismtoday.com/2018/12/04/understanding-common-knowledge/) gives an academic perspective. In other cases, you might want to know, say, why the language model outputs “A bed is a piece of chalk for painting.” If you're trying to use this to gather legal facts, they are not admissible (common knowledge or not) unless they're from a source cleared for use in court. And so on.

Answer (score 7):

> Are there powerful text generators that preserve attribution?

Not yet. The current solution is either post-hoc attribution, or doing some retrieval first before running some LLM on it (in which case one can attribute the retrieved document).

Related: [How can a language model keep track of the provenance of the main knowledge/sources used to generate a given output?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/38372/4)

Answer (score 7):

It's early days, but Tian Lan, Deng Cai, Yan Wang, Heyan Huang, and Xian-Ling Mao have released a paper, [Copy Is All You Need](https://arxiv.org/abs/2307.06962) ([peer-reviewed here](https://openreview.net/forum?id=CROlOA9Nd8C)). From the abstract:

> In this paper, we formulate text generation as progressively copying text segments (e.g., words or phrases) from an existing text collection. We compute the contextualized representations of meaningful text segments and index them using efficient vector search toolkits. The task of text generation is then decomposed into a series of copy-and-paste operations: at each time step, we seek suitable text spans from the text collection rather than selecting from a standalone vocabulary.

Appendix E contains three diagrams:

> [image: Figure 6, from page 16 of Copy Is All You Need. A passage is generated: “Unternehmen Asterisk ), was a battle fought in the Ardennes forest near the junction of the Rhine and Main rivers on 8 October”. Every region of text is attributed to a document, except isk ), and rivers which are attributed to the token vocabulary.]

There's still a bit of unattributable generation (in red), since there is still a core model trained in the usual way, but that model doesn't seem to need domain knowledge; one might be able to train it on a dataset that doesn't contain things that should be attributed.

Despite what this diagram shows, each copied phrase has *multiple* sources (Appendix D):

> Specifically, we treat each document as a sequence of tokens and scan each document from left to right. At each step, we search for the longest prefix of the unsegmented part that is also a sub-sequence of other documents other than the current document. If the length of that prefix is bigger than 2, we take that prefix as the next phrase. Otherwise, we take the first token as the next phrase and it is labeled as coming from the fixed token vocabulary.

However, this is not fundamental to the method: other segmentation algorithms are available. I would expect a segmentation algorithm based on grammatical boundaries to work well.

Answer (score 2):

I saw [GPT Researcher](https://github.com/assafelovic/gpt-researcher) recently posted [on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/singularity/comments/14vt3wj/excited_to_introduce_gptresearcher/).  It searches the Internet for relevant links, and incorporates them into a research document it produces.

> [image: Flowchart of GPT Researcher; image source: GPT researcher's GitHub account https://github.com/assafelovic/gpt-researcher]

I asked the developer on Reddit for an example PDF document, and they sent this: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nMJftTP31fhRNcJbywab2NDeDa1ZSxjr/view

> [image: Should I invest in the semiconductor industry in 2023?]

(skip pages [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7OQ4I.png) and [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QkjUO.png))

> [image: The fourth page showing references]

---

Another one like this is [Phind](https://www.phind.com/) which combines search with LLM.

> [image: screenshot of Phind being asked "What upcoming Marvel shows are there?" It begins with Loki Season 2, a summary and a web reference.]

Comment: This isn't quite what I was thinking of – there's no _trace_ of the provenance, and it could still say things that aren't in the sources, without any way to check other than manually going through and verifying it. Interesting that GPT models could be used like this, though!